# Integrate android support library into froyo platform

Tags: android, frameworks, platform, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working on an android image for a multimedia set top box. Since it is Froyo, I have to use the android support library to get fragments. Now, instead of including the library in every app, it would be much cleaner to integrate it into the android framework. I would also save some space.

I'm thinking of something like dexing the library and copying it to a specific location (, if that is possible at all).

Can you please give me some hints how to achieve this? Since the make system is not so well documented, a makefile would be even better.

**Edit:** I'm following pskinks approach to add the support library as framework lib. I have a make file, which copies the dexed support lib to `/system/framework/android.support.v4`.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Copy the support library
# This will install the file as /system/framework/android.support.v4
LOCAL_MODULE:= android.support.v4
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := android-support-v4.dex.jar
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_JAVA_LIBRARIES)
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

I also added the lib to the platform.xml file:

```
<library name="android.support.v4" 
         file="/system/framework/android.support.v4"/>
```

But, when the build process gets to the apps, which link against the lib, they fail, because the classes of the support lib are not available.

Here is the makefile of one of the apps:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := AppManager
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.support.v4
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

I also added the lib to manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="android.support.v4" android:required="true" />
```

What else do I have to do, that the build process knows about the library?

Answer (score 0):

see this http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7390b16854ac0dfa, i think it should work pretty the same on your stb

Comment: Thanks, pskink. I actually tried something like that, but didn't get the apps compiled, which depend on the library. Do you know, how the makefiles have to look like to work with the library?

Comment: sorry, i dont use makefiles